# Can't connect to database by calling function in class using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection, database-connection

I'm stuck in that situation that when I use `$this->conn` it returns:

> Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

but if I don't use it, then it said:

> Undefined variable: conn

```php
class save extends forma
{
    private $servername = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $dbname = 'world';

    public $conn;

    protected $table;

    private function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->table)
            die('No table name provided');
    }


    function connect()
    {

        $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die($this->conn->connect_error);
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function saugoti($id,$pakeitimui=0, $kas=0)
    {

        $this->connect();
        if(isset($_POST['saugoti']))
        {
            $table = "bmp_test";

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $pav = $_POST['pav'];
            $adr = $_POST['adr'];
            $tel = $_POST['tel'];

            if ($pakeitimui == 0)
            {
                $sql1 = "SHOW FIELDS FROM $table ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql1);
```

Comment: Can you show where the error is pointing to?

Comment: I think `$conn = new mysqli(...` should be `$this->conn = new mysqli(...`. Same goes for `$conn->connect_error` and `$conn->query`.

Comment: `return $conn;` instead of `return $this->conn` and `$conn->connect_error` instead of `$this->conn->connect_error`;

Comment: And `$conn->query($sql1);` where `$conn` is a local variable, not defined - should use `$this->conn` after fixing it in the `connect()` method

Comment: "$result = $conn->query($sql1);" here, but only in that case if i don't write "$this->connect();" because this way i also get error for using $this->

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the *class* variable `$conn` everywhere (this will be written as `$this->conn`) instead of `$conn` (which is a *local* variable).

Replacing all occurences of `$conn` by `$this->conn` in your code will solve that problem.

Answer (score -2):

The main reason it was not working is you are using `$this->conn->connect_error` in connect function while storing connection in `$conn` which is local variable and not class variable

If you dont want to call `$this->connect();` in every function then below code might work for you

```
class save extends forma
{
    private $servername = 'localhost';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $dbname = 'world';

    public $conn;

    protected $table = 'test_table';

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->table)
            die('No table name provided');
        $this->connect();
    }


    function connect()
    {

        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);

        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
             
            die($this->conn->connect_error);
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function saugoti($id,$pakeitimui=0, $kas=0)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['saugoti']))
        {
            $table = "bmp_test";

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $pav = $_POST['pav'];
            $adr = $_POST['adr'];
            $tel = $_POST['tel'];

            if ($pakeitimui == 0)
            {
                $sql1 = "SHOW FIELDS FROM $table ";
                $result = $this->conn->query($sql1);
```